# My vpn is connected but i cannot browse internet

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, vpn

i have problem with vpn recently i can connect with vpn but not with internet, ping shows up to 200ms more.

```
mtr -rw api.protonvpn.ch


Start: 2021-11-20T16:49:27+0700
HOST: nonely                                         Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 192.168.90.1                                  0.0%    10    3.6   4.4   2.6  12.9   3.0
  2.|-- 172.16.16.199                                 0.0%    10   22.0  25.4  19.8  40.4   6.8
  3.|-- 172-13-1-199.lightspeed.mssnks.sbcglobal.net  0.0%    10   20.6  24.6  13.8  37.0   7.3
  4.|-- 10.5.192.1                                    0.0%    10   22.1 123.6  22.1 375.5 126.4
  5.|-- 180.252.1.161                                 0.0%    10   32.4 109.4  15.8 377.2 122.8
  6.|-- 180.240.190.109                              60.0%    10   60.5 158.1  60.5 425.5 178.4
  7.|-- 180.240.190.109                              70.0%    10   46.3 103.0  46.3 201.4  85.5
  8.|-- 180.240.204.104                               0.0%    10   46.3 145.0  44.2 486.8 148.2
  9.|-- tge6-4.fr3.sin.llnw.net                       0.0%    10   45.5 142.8  41.5 500.0 152.0
10.|-- siteprotect.security.neustar                  0.0%    10   43.9 138.7  41.3 499.4 148.6
11.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
12.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
14.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
15.|-- gre01.sin.siteprotect.security.neustar       20.0%    10   62.8 186.1  34.9 640.6 208.6
16.|-- 156.154.253.7                                 0.0%    10  240.5 317.4 227.2 677.9 148.6
17.|-- 172.17.12.19                                  0.0%    10  222.9 292.6 209.8 609.3 134.7
18.|-- 185.159.159.170                               0.0%    10  215.5 217.8 209.4 242.6   9.6




cat /etc/resolv.conf

#Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
#127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
#run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
 
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218 
nameserver 192.168.90.1 
search itotolink.net

ping -c 4 api.protonvpn.ch

    PING api.protonvpn.ch (185.159.159.170) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=219 ms
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=234 ms
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=436 ms
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=635 ms

nslookup api.protonvpn.ch

;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
```

my nslookup is not working for all servers or url what happend with my configuration? hmm... is there something wrong with my router? I don't think so, I haven't tampered with the router settings since I bought it